# Trying to use aspnet_regiis running Powershell remotely. Error: Object already exists

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use a Powershell script to run aspnet_regiis on a remote computer.

I have done a number of experiments.

If I run it directly on the target machine,it works correctly. These are the steps. I am running Powershell as Administrator:

`Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "name"`

That gets me in.

Then I run Set-Location to get to the correct path.

Then I run my ps1 file.

`.\EncryptConfig.ps1`

It does some preliminary stuff. Deletes web.config if it exists. Renames the App.Config file to web.config. Does that all OK. Then it tries to run aspnet_regiis:

`` $rpath="$Env:Windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -pef `"connectionStrings`" `"$TargetDir`"" ``

`invoke-expression $rpath`

This is where the error occurs. (Failed to encrypt the section 'connectionStrings' using provider 'RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'. Error message from the provider: Object already exists.)

I checked that I have the correct credentials:

`write-output ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")`
`True`

Is it possible to do this? If so, how?

Comment: Where is this script? On the IIS box or on your work station? You cannot run local scripts on remote machines without properly setting that up. You cannot use local variables in a remote session without properly setting that up. You cannot run Invoke* on a remote host unless you are in the local admin group on the remote host. Don't use invoke-expression, you are exposing yourself to unnecessary code injection risks. Look up about Powershell Remoting, remote functions/variables, About Scope and invoke expression harmful.

Comment: I am running this script on my own workstation. The script is running, apart from that aspnet_regiis command, so I would presume that it is properly set up!